# Angularjs fire parent controller on nested routes

Tags: angularjs, routes

I have a challenge with nested routes, in angular js, here is snippet in app.js

```
...
    when('/profile/:id', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/profile',
        controller: 'profileCtrl'
    }).
    when('/profile/:id/editTaskList', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/editTaskList',
        controller: 'checkListCtrl',
        activeMenu: 'editTaskList'
    }). 
...
```

I want to have to access to the **"profile data"** in every single route under the "/profile/:id".

**"Profile Data"** example is :

```
{
   user: "demo",
   title: "dev"
}
```

and it comes through AJAX(JSON) based on the ID in the routs

The  way how it is setup now, is having  a service to get the User profile and I make the service request for the profile ID in "**profileCtrl**".

The problem that I have, if someone share the url and goes right away  to "/profile/:id/editTaskList", the "profileCtrl" doesn't fire .

**I don't think by adding service request in "checkListCtrl"  is a good practice , because I'll have more nested routes under the "profile" and it will require to duplicate the code in multiple controllers.**

What is the best practice to fix this issue ? For me would work as well if i can fire "profileCtrl" all the time when we are "/profile/:id" or lower

Answer (score 0):

you can get your data before you controllers are initalized

```
...
    when('/profile/:id', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/profile',
        controller: 'profileCtrl',
        resolve: {
         profile: ['ProfileService','$route', function (ProfileService,$route) {
                 return  ProfileService.getProfile($route.current.params.id);
            }]

        },
    }).
    when('/profile/:id/editTaskList', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/editTaskList',
        controller: 'checkListCtrl',
         resolve: {
         profile: ['ProfileService','$route', function (ProfileService,$route) {
                 return  ProfileService.getProfile($route.current.params.id);
            }]

        },
        activeMenu: 'editTaskList'
    }). 
...
```

controller will be

```
function myCtrl($scope,profile){
// now profile is your data 
}
```